# Is there a way to call a function gas with javascript parameters?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on google site, and i have 2 files: 'code.gs' which contains a function with 2 parameters, and 'affichage.html' which contains my HTML code.
I want to call thatfunction in 'affichage' with parameters that are in html file. do you have any ideas?

```js
 function getFileIdFromFolder(folder_name,photo_name){
            var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);
            while (folders.hasNext()) {
                var folder = folders.next();
                var files = folder.getFilesByName(file_name);
                while (files.hasNext()) {
                     var file = files.next();
                     return file.getId();
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <html>
       <script>
         var folder_name="folder";
         var file_name = "file";
         <? getFileIdFromFolder(folder,file); ?> 
       </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: What you describe is basic functionality and is well documented in the guide to html service, under client-server communication. Reviewing core documentation is a requirement and prerequisite of asking a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: @tehhowch the case i am describing is not including in the documentation, i read it well. i m looking for a way to use javascript variable as gas parameters

Comment: It seems you want to get the fileId when the page loads.  You could use createTemplateFromFile before the page loads or google.script.run after.

Comment: `google.script.run.getFileIdFromFolder(folder_name,file_name)` Then use appropriate success handler to update html client side. Pay attention to what you read, if you did indeed read.

Comment: Your goal here appears to be to use templated html which is slower and less flexible than the asynchronous pattern that is recommended. In which case your issue is that you need to review the different kinds of scriptlets and fix your typos, and review how to convert the HTML file to a template and then evaluate and convert it to `HtmlOutput`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
  <script>
    var foldername="folder";
    var filename = "file";
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(id){
      document.getElementById('displaydiv').innerHTML='<p>'+ id + '</p>';
    })
    .getFileIdFromFolder(foldername,filename);  
  </script>
</html>
```

- [Client Server Communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: I think your missing a period before getFileIdFromFolder

Comment: Thank you, it is working. @TheWizEd , no it's correction, one line of code